# InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified при удалении элементов в цикле foreach

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем добрый день! Создаю 2D игру на Unity. В скрипте есть список(List<>) объектов и при определённых условиях один из объектов удаляется из списка. Но когда это происходит появляется исключение "InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".Пожалуйста,
подскажите в чём здесь проблема.

```
   public class PaintingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<PaintingOver> _unpaintedWalls;

    private void Update()
    {
        foreach (var wall in _unpaintedWalls)
        {
            if (wall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != wall._defaultColor)
            {
                _unpaintedWalls.Remove(wall);
                Debug.Log(_unpaintedWalls.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `_unpaintedWalls.RemoveAll(_unpaintedWalls.Where(ваше условие));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен `for` с конца и тогда сдвиг при удаления элемента `List` не будет иметь значение.

```
List<int> YourList = new List<int>();
for (int i = YourList.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (YourList[i] == 7)
        YourList.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: Если цикл делать до list.length, то количество циклов изменится, разве нет?

Comment: Спасибо за решение

Comment: @tym32167, да, херню понаписал.

Answer (score 3):

Это происходит из-за того, что нельзя изменять коллекцию во время её прохождения. Есть три способа исправить это:

```cs
foreach (var wall in new List<PaintingOver>(_unpaintedWalls))
{
    if (wall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != wall._defaultColor)
    {
        _unpaintedWalls.Remove(wall);
        Debug.Log(_unpaintedWalls.Count);
    }
}
```

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < _unpaintedWalls.Length; i++)
{
    if (_unpaintedWalls[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != _unpaintedWalls[i]._defaultColor)
    {
        _unpaintedWalls[i].RemoveAt(i--)
        Debug.Log(_unpaintedWalls.Count);
    }
}
```

```cs
var removeList = new List<PaintingOver>();

foreach (var wall in _unpaintedWalls)
{
    if (wall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != wall._defaultColor)
    {
        removeList.Add(wall);
        Debug.Log(_unpaintedWalls.Count);
    }
}

_unpaintedWalls = _unpaintedWalls.Except(removeList).ToList();
```

Comment: А можно просто `foreach (var wall in new List<PaintingOver>( _unpaintedWalls))....`

Comment: А можно еще проще `foreach (var wall in _unpaintedWalls.ToList())`

Answer (score 0):

Вижу решения уже есть, но хочу добавить вариант с LINQ:

```
private void Update() => 
    _unpaintedWalls = 
        _unpaintedWalls
            .Where(wall => wall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == wall._defaultColor)
            .ToList();
```

Но с `Log` такое решение не красиво.